# how to call a function in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

How would I go about designating a portion of my assembly code as a function and calling that function from within the _asm {} block? Let's say for example, I wanted the function to start at the for loop,  "n" elements are filled with a value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void printBytes(char *data, int length)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        if ((x & 0xF) == 0) printf("\n");
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)data[x]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return;
} // printBytes

void function(){

    char string[] = "The end is near!";
    void* dst = &string;
    unsigned char value = 0xA5;
    int nCount = 5;

    printf("The message is: %s\n", string);
    printBytes(string, strlen(string)); 

    __asm {

        //type cast the str from void* to char*
            mov eax, DWORD PTR [dst]
            mov DWORD PTR [ebp-88], eax

        //fill "n" elements/blocks with value
            mov DWORD PTR [ebp-76], 0
            jmp label_3
        label_2:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp-76]
            add eax, 1
            mov DWORD PTR [ebp-76], eax
        label_3:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-76]
            cmp eax, DWORD PTR [nCount]
            jge EXIT

            mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-88]
            add eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-76]
            mov cl, BYTE PTR [value]
            mov BYTE PTR[eax], cl
            jmp label_2
        EXIT:

    }// asm_memset */

    printf("Now the message is: %s\n", string);
    printBytes(string, strlen(string));
    return;

}

int main() {

    function();

    printf("Press ENTER key to continue...");
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: as a side note, the code runs fine as is. It's just for an assignment I'd like to demonstrate how to call a function in assembly language.

Comment: Use real assembly instead of inline is how you might do it so avoid any stack and return issues.  inline asm is compiler specific which compiler is this for and what did the documentation say on the subject?

Comment: i'm compiling it with Intel C/C++. I'll look for the documentation online, that's a good idea

Comment: as written your code probably needs more stuff in the asm definition to avoid registers and data in the asm to avoid conflicts with the compiler generated code.   some tools will let you put the inline asm outside of a function and in that case it is real asm like and you would setup a normal stack frame, preserve non-volatile items and call the subfunction(s), whatever language they are written in (conforming to the calling conventions of course.

Comment: You can put an `asm{}` block in a dummy function that you never call with C.  You can use labels there to define a function.  (You can declare it as a `declspec(naked)` function if you want so you can call the C name.)

Comment: I think it's also possible to place an `_asm` statement outside of a function.  You can then define your own function by starting it with a label.  Refer to the manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the solution to your problem is likely to be non-portable.

You will need to find the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for your architecture/system/compiler, and comply with its calling conventions.